# How to change private class variable by onChange event in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia, slickgrid, aurelia-templating

I want to listen to onChange event in a "odata-table" which is part of the aurelia-slickgrid library(https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid), take the value from that event and pass it to a variable in the class.
Here is part the class in Typescript:

```
private selectedPeriod;

public onCellChanged(e) {
   this.selectedPeriod = e.target.defaultValue
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div>
 <odata-table
            if.bind="businessUnit"
            update.bind="creditsTableUpdate"
            id-property-name="Id"
            onchange.bind="onCellChanged"
            column-definitions.bind="creditsColumnDefinition">
        </odata-tabled>
    </div>
```

There is the **onChange.bind** passing the **onCellChanged**.
And when I do a console log  **selectedPeriod** somewhere else in the code, it gives this error:

> undefined

Comment: It looks like you're using SlickGrid with Aurelia but at the same time it doesn't entirely look like Aurelia-Slickgrid (which I created), in that case it would be `<aurelia-slickgrid>`, so which lib are you referring to exactly? It's not mentioned in your question

Comment: Yes, in my case the odata-table sits on top of the <aurelia-slickrid> and that's the library I am using. I went to the wiki in Github and tried to make use of the OnCellChange method, but it does not work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you might be using the wrong event name and also the wrong way to watch events. Events are not bindable, you need to use `delegate` with Aurelia.

You can see all the built-in SlickGrid grid event names at this link, [Grid events](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events) and by looking at the list, the event name you should be using is `onCellChange` and must be written as kebab-case in Aurelia, so the final event name that you should be using is `on-cell-change.delegate`

Here's a full demo of this (refer to Aurelia-Slickgrid [Event Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Grid-&-DataView-Events#1-example-with-delegate-event-dispatch-asgonx))

```html
  <aurelia-slickgrid 
    grid-id="gridId" 
    column-definitions.bind="columnDefs" 
    grid-options.bind="gridOptions" 
    dataset.bind="myDataset"
    on-cell-change.delegate="onCellChanged($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)">
  </aurelia-slickgrid>
```